# Animate only insert but not delete/reload

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that I am calling `performBatchUpdates(...)` to do `reloadSections`, `insertSections` and `deleteSections` within the block.

I would only want to animate `insertSections` with spring animation but not the rest. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried wrapping `insertSections` within a `UIView.animate(...)` block or wrap the rest within `UIView.performWithoutAnimation(...)` but the UI is pretty choppy.

Comment: Do you want to instantly show the deletions and reloads then animate the inserts or the other way around?

Comment: @rmaddy the former. And they have to be put in the same `performBatchUpdates` block, otherwise the indexes will be wrong

Comment: That's a problem. You can do this if your "insert" indexes are based on the updated collection view after the deletions are completed.